# To run a program though cmd in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\rs40dk\relap.exe -i simple_pipe_1.i -o sys.o -r sys.r"
        p.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to call `cmd` window and I want another program run in `cmd` through VB.NET code and run.

After running it should provide output in the required folder.

I write the code but `cmd` opens in `Debug` folder of the project not in the `C:\` and it couldn't run the program. Just open the folder.

I am trying it for a week but I am struck in it. I would appreciate help.

Comment: "C:\Users\Sheikh\Desktop\cmd command\WindowsApplication6\WindowsApplication6\bin\
Debug>" ...... When 'cmd' opens it follows above path. kindly I want that it should follow the path mentioned in code.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c foo/bar.exe")
```